# Drawing outside content insets with drawGlyphsForGlyphRange

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nstextview, nslayoutmanager

I'm trying to show some extra symbols next to lines in `NSTextView`, based on text attributes.

I have successfully subclassed `NSLayoutManager`, but it seems that layout manager can't draw outside the area set by `textContainerInset`.

Because my text view can potentially have a very long strings, I'm hoping to keep the drawing connected to displaying glyphs. Is there a way to trick the layout manager to be able to draw inside the content insets — or is there another method I use instead of `drawGlyphsForGlyphRange`?

I have tried calling `super` before and after drawing, as well as storing and not storing graphics state. I also attempted `setDrawsOutsideLineFragment:YES` for the glyphs, but with no luck.

Things like Xcode editor itself uses change markers, so I know that this is somehow doable, but it's very possible I'm looking from the wrong place.

My drawing method, simplified:

```objectivec
- (void)drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphsToShow atPoint:(NSPoint)origin {
    [super drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphsToShow atPoint:origin];
    
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = self.textStorage;
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = self.textContainers[0];
    
    NSRange glyphRange = glyphsToShow;
    NSSize offset = self.textContainers.firstObject.textView.textContainerInset;
        
    while (glyphRange.length > 0) {
        NSRange charRange = [self characterRangeForGlyphRange:glyphRange actualGlyphRange:NULL], attributeCharRange, attributeGlyphRange;
        
        id attribute = [textStorage attribute:@"Revision" atIndex:charRange.location longestEffectiveRange:&attributeCharRange inRange:charRange];
        attributeGlyphRange = [self glyphRangeForCharacterRange:attributeCharRange actualCharacterRange:NULL];
        attributeGlyphRange = NSIntersectionRange(attributeGlyphRange, glyphRange);

        if (attribute != nil) {
            [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
            
            NSRect boundingRect = [self boundingRectForGlyphRange:attributeGlyphRange
                                                  inTextContainer:textContainer];
            
            // Find the top of the revision
            NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(offset.width - 20, offset.height + boundingRect.origin.y + 1.0);
            
            NSString *marker = @"*";
            
            [marker drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:@{
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.blackColor;
            }];
                                   
            [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
        }
                
        glyphRange.length = NSMaxRange(glyphRange) - NSMaxRange(attributeGlyphRange);
        glyphRange.location = NSMaxRange(attributeGlyphRange);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a vertical ruler? See [NSRulerView how to correctly align line numbers with main text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672218/nsrulerview-how-to-correctly-align-line-numbers-with-main-text)

Comment: AFAIK, a vertical `NSRulerView` cannot be positioned anywhere else except on the left side. I tried several hacks to make it invisible and move it around, but with no luck.

However, looking at how ruler views work and are updated, I think it might be possible to create a similar view of my own, and have `drawGlyphsForGlyphRange` update its contents when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was much more simple than I anticipated.

You can set `lineFragmentPadding` for the associated `NSTextContainer` to make more room for drawing in the margins. This has to be taken into account when setting insets for the text container.